OpenLiberty Authentication: Adding roles to Principal
We are using OpenLiberty 24.0.0.x with openIdConnectClient (https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/config/openidConnectClient.html).
This is our configuration:
 <openidConnectClient id="webapp_oidc_client"
                         clientId="${OIDC_CLIENT_ID}"
                         clientSecret="${OIDC_CLIENT_SECRET}"
                         discoveryEndpointUrl="${OIDC_DISCOVERY_URI}"
                         userIdentifier="uid"
                         signatureAlgorithm="RS256"
                         scope="openid"
                         responseType="code"
                         useNonce="true"
                         pkceCodeChallengeMethod="S256"
                         preferredJwsAlgorithm="RS256"
                         useSystemPropertiesForHttpClientConnections="true">
    </openidConnectClient>

Everything works fine. Due to some organisational constraints, we cannot send the group information of a user in the JWT claims.
So we need to deliver the group information from a proprietary system, which provides only group information of a user (We can call an REST interface).
We need to add group information after the authentication process to the Principal, so we can use the standard mechanism in our code like @RolesAllowed.
I'm searching for a hook like SecurityIdentityAugmentor in Quarkus.
(https://quarkus.io/guides/security-customization#security-identity-customization)
In Spring the is a kind LdapAuthoritiesPopulator to add roles
(https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/userdetails/LdapAuthoritiesPopulator.html)
Do you have any ideas or hints. I searched the official documentation of OpenLiberty, but didn't find anything.
If you need any further information, please ask.

This might be what you're looking for https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/base?topic=security-public-apis.
That API allows you to access the security subject.
